Is the $n$-th prime with remainder $1$ when divided by $4$ always greater than the $n$-th prime with remainder $3$ when divided by $4$?
Is this rule of prime numbers correct?
The $n$-th prime number that leaves a remainder of $1$ when divided by $4$ always greater than the $n$-th prime number that leaves a remainder of $3$ when divided by $4$.

See the Chebyshev Bias

See also this American Mathematical Monthly article: https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/PNR.pdf

The paper @Vincent linked to is an excellent one.

A quick search using a computer yields a negative answer, where the smallest counterexample occurs at $n = 1473$.
The $1473$-th prime leaving remainder $1$ when divided by $4$ is $26861$.
Meanwhile the $1473$-th prime leaving remainder $3$ when divided by $4$ is $26863$.
